# parse html as php with htaccess prompts to downloading

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a html site and I want html pages to be parsed as php; I'm using a htaccess file for that.

On the online server, it works properly. The command is:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

However, on localhost server it doesn't work at all. When I access the page, it prompts to download the file instead of displaying the page.

I'm using PHP 5.6.3 and PHP as module, I guess.

I tried all sorts of similar commands in htaccess, like:

- `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`
- `AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm`
- `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`
- `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm`
- `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`
- `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm`
- `AddHandler x-mapp-php .html .htm`
- `AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .html .htm`

but no luck.

I also tried `RemoveHandler .html .htm` but without success.

I checked the httpd.conf file and among others, there are the following:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files/PHP/php5apache2_4.dll"

AllowOverride All

<Directory "D:/mysites/">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Where should I look for anything wrong then..?

Any hint appreciated.

Comment: If you download the file has the downloaded file been processed by PHP? What `Content-Type` header is being sent? (My bet would be on the first `AddType` in your list.)

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this :

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

But it's better to add it in your vhost or if it's possible, blogbally in your apache2.conf.